# Field Not Creating In MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to make this field in one of my models for a project. However this is not working and I am unable to figure it out.

```
funds:{

    remainingFunds: Number,
    newfund: [{
        fund: Number,           
        reason: String,
        typeOfTransaction: String,
        modified: {type:Date,default:Date.now}

    }]

}
```

Error:

E:\YelpCamp_CheckImageUpload\models\campgrounds.js:42
        newfund: {
               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Can you please post all the code for the model?

Comment: Actually. I found the mistake. I had the Closing bracket of the whole document at the wrong place.